# Behavior of vector's reserve( ) method 

Tags: c++, methods, stdvector

I wanted to know the behavior of `std::vector::reserve()` in following situations:

1. Suppose `reserve(N)` is called multiple times one after another immediately.
   Will the earlier `reserve(N1)` get added up or overwritten ?
2. If the earlier `reserve(N1)` gets overwritten with the latest call,
   then what happens if the latest `reserve(Nn)` demands less number of slots ?
3. After declaring `vector` if we have simply `push_back()` X elements,
   and then we call `reserve(N)`. Will the already `push_back()` X
   elements counted in `N` ?
4. Suppose, if the `vector` has some X pushed elements and now if we
   `push_back()` 1 more element (X+1), then that object would have to
   get relocated; but we haven't yet performed `push_back()`. What
   happens if we call `reserve()` now ? Will the object get relocated
   immediately ? If not, then how is the space reserved ?

Comment: If you don't have a copy of the standard handy, there are [multiple](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html) [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) online.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`reserve()` just makes sure that the vector's allocated memory is *at least* large enough to contain the number of items passed as its argument. Thus...

1. Whichever the max value of all those passed will be the minimum resulting capacity effectively reserved.
2. See #1.
3. Yes.
4. The vector allocates as much memory when `reserve()` is called as is necessary to store the number of items passed to `reserve()`.

---

To quote from the actual standard:

```
void reserve(size_type n)
```

> If `n` is less than or equal to `capacity()`, this call has no effect.
>   Otherwise, it is a request for allocation of additional memory. If the
>   request is successful, then `capacity()` is greater than or equal to `n`;
>   otherwise, `capacity()` is unchanged. In either case, `size()` is
>   unchanged.

Comment: +1 It is also important to keep in mind that if a reallocation occurs (`n` > `capacity()`); iterators, pointers and references to that vector will be invalidated. With that in mind, `reserve()` is especially useful to actually *prevent a reallocation* (and thus the invalidation of iterators, etc.) when `push_back()` is called.

Comment: #1 is inaccurate: having _at least_ as much as `reserve()` asked means the resulting _capacity_ (not size!) might be larger than the call to `reserve()` with the largest request.

Comment: Edited "resulting size" -> "minimum resulting size".

Comment: The problem is't "minimum". You're talking about the size _of the allocated memory_, which is confusing in the presence of `vector::size()`. The canonical term for "size of allocated memory, whether used or just reserved" is `vector::capacity()`.

Comment: If we want to be pedantic, yes. A capacity is still a size, just not a `::size()`.

Answer (score 5):

> Suppose `reserve(N)` is called multiple times one after another immediately. Will the earlier `reserve(N1)` get added up or overwritten ?

Unlike `std::string` it is not possible to call `reserve()` for `std::vector` to shrink the `capacity()`.Calling `reserve()` with an argument that is less than the current `capacity()` is a no-op. Hence the last `reserve()` call which increases the current capacity will hold good.

> If the earlier `reserve(N1)` gets overwritten with the latest call, then what happens if the latest `reserve(Nn)` demands less number of slots ?

Calling `reserve()` with an argument that is less than the current `capacity()` is a no-op.

> After declaring vector if we have simply push_back() X elements, and then we call reserve(N). Will the already push_back() X elements counted in N ?

`reserve()` just allocates(reserves) enough number of elements so Yes. Note that after calling `reserve()` only the `capacity()` of the vector is changed the `size()` remains unaffected.If you would need to create as many elements and not just reserve memory you should be using `resize()`.

> Suppose, if the vector has some `X` pushed elements and now if we `push_back()` 1 more element `(X+1)`, then that object would have to get relocated; but we haven't yet performed `push_back()`. What happens if we call `reserve()` now ? Will the object get relocated immediately ? If not, then how is the space reserved ?

Yes, the relocation will happen but it depends. As said before, `reserve()` allocates enough memory to store as many elements as the argument passed to it. So if this number of elements is greater than what can be accommodated in current vector `capacity()`, relocation will happen.

Standard References:
**C++03 23.2.4.2 vector capacity [lib.vector.capacity]**

> `void reserve(size_type n);`
>
> **Effects:** A directive that informs a vector of a planned change in size, so that it can manage the storage allocation accordingly. After `reserve()`, `capacity()` is greater or equal to the argument of reserve if reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of `capacity()` otherwise. Reallocation happens at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of `reserve()`.
>
> **Complexity:** It does not change the size of the sequence and takes at most linear time in the size of the sequence.
>
> **Throws:** length_error if `n > max_size()`.248)
>
> **Notes:** Reallocation invalidates all the references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements in the sequence. It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the size specified in the most recent call to `reserve()`.